# Java for loop decrementing

Tags: java, for-loop

can you guys pls help me

i want to code where the user will enter a number and then using for loop it will display the number in decrement for example:

Enter a number: 4

OUTPUT:
4
4-3
4-3-2
4-3-2-1
3
3-2
3-2-1
2
2-1
1-1

code it using for loop

this is my attempt code i'm getting confused:

```
  for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
         {
               System.out.print(i+ "-" );
          for (int k = num; k>=i; k--)
             {
                System.out.print(k);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: You should be able to do this using a **single** `for` loop *and* match your exact pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loop and recursion, like in the sample below:

```
public static void doDecrement(int n)
  {
    String a = "";
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
    {

      a += i;
      System.out.println(a + (n == 1 ? "-" + n : ""));
      a += "-";

    }
    --n;
    if (n != 0)
      doDecrement(n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    for (int i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.println(i);
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
            for (int k = i; k >= j; k--) {
                System.out.print(k);
                if (k > j) {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
int i, j, n, x = n = 4;
String[] a = new String[x];
for (i = x; i >= 1; i--) a[n - i] = String.valueOf(i);
for (i = n; i >= 1; i--, n = a.length) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        s.append(String.join("-", Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, j + 1)));
        s.append('\n');
    }
    a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
}
```

```
4
4-3
4-3-2
4-3-2-1
3
3-2
3-2-1
2
2-1
1
```